# How do I read the GPS data from a GPS device using Java

Tags: gps, java

I want to read data from a GPS device connected to my laptop and find the latitude and longitude. I searched a lot about it but could only find Android related programs.

How do I read the GPS data using Java (and not Android)?

Comment: vist these links, I think they can solve your problem:
http://javagps.sourceforge.net/ and http://javanmea.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at them